# How to import Google Fonts to HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I can't get the [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) font to work in my HTML file. If I understand correctly, Google's instruction are:

"Copy these lines into your `head` tag":

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>This is a heading</h3>
    <p>This is a string.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of the Roboto font, the website shows the standard font:

[image]

Comment: Do you have CSS saying it should _use_ that font anywhere?

Comment: No I don't. Ill look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before  `</head>`

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use font family in css, use like this

```
<style>
body, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```